# a quadratic form's question

Tags: polynomials

#### a quadratic form

---

a curve

$$\begin{align*}\text{ax}^2+\text{bxy}+\text{cy}^2+\text{dx}+\text{ey}+f\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}\text{ax}^2+2\text{bxy}+\text{cy}^2+2\text{dx}+2\text{ey}+f\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

the matrix of (1) is

$$\begin{align*}\begin{array}{ccc} a & \frac{b}{2} & \frac{d}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c & \frac{e}{2} \\ \frac{d}{2} & \frac{e}{2} & f \\\end{array}\end{align*}$$

the matrix of (2) is

$$\begin{align*}\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & d \\ b & c & e \\ d & e & f \\\end{array}\end{align*}$$

$b=\frac{b}{2}+\frac{b}{2}$, question 1: what's the meaning of the addition in Matrix?

I know the Trace is the summation of elements of the dominant diagonal.

question 2: What's the realtionship between (1) and (2)

Comment: It represents pair of straight line.If this is a equation then by factoring it we can find out two equations of straight lines.https://www.dropbox.com/s/lttzfzchg6djrl8/ch04.pdf   https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxhw270d0gm3ijm/ch07.pdf

Comment: Actually, the equation represents a conic section curve. In certain special cases, the conic will degenerate into a pair of lines. Your second link goes to a document about XSLT transforms, which probably doesn't help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two equations give two different ways to represent conic section curves. Take a look at [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic#Matrix_notation) for some background.

If you use equation (1), then you get (almost) the matrix form that you showed. Your matrix is not quite right, it should be:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
a   & b/2 & d/2    \\
b/2 & c   & e/2  \\
d/2 & e/2 & f
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
The only problem with this matrix is that lots of elements involve division by two, which makes things harder to read and understand. So, it's nicer if we use equation (2), instead, because that can be written in matrix form using the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
a   & b  & d    \\
b   & c  & e  \\
d   & e  & f
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
The second matrix looks nicer, so people often choose to use equation (2) to represent a conic section curve, rather than equation (1). Both equations represent the same kinds of curves, though.

So, for example, the curve 
$$
x^2 + 5xy + 4y + 9 = 0
$$
would be written in the form of equation (2) as 
$$
x^2 + 2\left(\frac52\right)xy + 2(2)y + 9 = 0
$$
In other words, we would use $a=1$, $b=\tfrac52$, $c=0$, $d=0$, $e=2$, $f=9$.